# string.replace replacing all occurences

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm trying to make `string.replace` replace all words except ones starting with a certain character, e.g. ~, but if i have a word with only one letter, that letter gets deleted from the words i want to stay

**Code**

```
import re

st1 = "dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"

for i in re.findall(r"\b(?<!~)\w+", st1):
    st1 = st1.replace(i, "")

print(st1)
```

What I want to happen:

Input:
`"dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"`

Output:
`"~shark ~squid"`

What happens:

Input:
`"dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"`

Output:
`"~shrk ~squid"`

I think this is happening because it's replacing all instances of 'a', including the ones within other words. How do I ensure it only deletes the instance intended?

Comment: You need to regex replace so you replace the matches group, not a separate string replacement.

Comment: About this string, can there be multiple spaces between words or perhaps punctuation? If so, do you want to keep them in the result?

Comment: `re.sub(r"\b(?<!~)\w+\s*", "", st1).strip()` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually suggest using a regex find all approach here:

```py
st1 = "dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"
matches = re.findall(r'~\w+', st1)
output = " ".join(matches)
print(output)  # ~shark ~squid
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know str.join existed lol.

Comment: If you're only interested in printing the result then str.join is unnecessary - print(*re.findall(r'~\w+', st1))

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you don't really need *re* for this. Just split the string into tokens (words) and examine the first character of each token as follows:

```
st1 = "dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"
print(*filter(lambda s: s[0] == "~", st1.split()))
```

**Output:**

```
~shark ~squid
```

**Note:**

Although more concise, this runs slower than the *re* approach (Python 3.12.1, Apple Silicon M2)

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression you have used "\b(?<!~)\w+" is matching single letters also. To address this, I have modified the regular expression to exclude single letters using the pattern \b(?<!~)\w{1}\b|\b(?<!~)\w{2,}\b. This pattern would correctly matches words with two or more characters, excluding those starting with '~' and single-letter words.

```
    import re
    
st1 = "dolphin fish ~shark eel octopus ~squid a"

pattern = r'\b(?<!~)\w{1}\b|\b(?<!~)\w{2,}\b'

result = re.sub(pattern, "", st1)

print(result)
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to keep the "a" but rather to make sure that words that match substrings don't replace those substrings in the accepted words. Your result is "  ~shark   ~squid a", not the string wanted.